# Oracle: Need correct TYPE for cursor record with dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to evaluate the cardinality of existing parent-child relationships between tables. I store information about the relationships in metadata and will build dynamic SQL to evaluate each relationship. My results will look something like this:

```
CHILD_CNT       COUNT(*)
---------     ----------
        0              3
        1              2
        2              3
        3              5
        4              8
        5              4
        7              3
       11              1
```

This means that there are three "parents" with no child records, two with one child, etc.

The code I tried looks like this:

```
procedure check_card_for_relship as

  vStmt         varchar2(32760 byte);
  type vRefCursor is ref cursor;
  cChildCntCursor vRefCursor;
  rChildCntCursor t_child_cnt;

begin
    -- The SQL statement will actually be built from a 
    -- metadata database, but this is an example of how 
    -- a finished query would look.
  vStmt := '
    select
      child_cnt
      , count(*)
    from
      (
        select
          p.empid
          , (
              select count(*)
              from pilot_training_recs c -- Child table
              where c.empid = p.empyid
            ) child_cnt
        from
          employee p  -- Parent Table
        where
          p.is_pilot_flag = 1
      )
      group by child_cnt
      order by child_cnt
    ';

  open cChildCntCursor for vStmt;
  loop
    fetch cChildCntCursor into rChildCntCursor;
    exit when cChildCntCursor%notfound;
    --
    -- My processing here...
    --
  end loop;
  close cChildCntCursor;

end check_card_for_relship;
```

The type t_child_cnt is defined this way:

```
create or replace type t_child_cnt as object 
  (
      cardinality_value number
    , cardinality_cnt number
  );
```

Since the child_cnt value is a count(*) in the subquery and the outer count(*) is a count of the counts I thought that maybe those would both be a data type of number. Either that's not right or I'm doing something else wrong. My error is this:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at "METADATA_MANIPULATION", line 36
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

I don't find expected "-" but got "-" to be too helpful! I may be using ref cursor wrong. I'm not experienced with it. But from what I have read this is the common approach to defining a cursor when you are using dynamic SQL. Those examples all relied on a record type from an existing table which doesn't fit my situation. Thanks.

Comment: Anton, your first suggestion worked great. When I posted the code I simplified some things and put in the comment before the SQL string about building it from metadata. There really is a parameter to the procedure that indicates which relationship to evaluate. So it does have to be dynamic, sorry if that misled you. So I don't think I can use the last two methods. I do agree that it would be better to strongly type if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch record into object.

Try

```
select 
     t_child_cnt(child_cnt, count(*)) 
   from
```

instead of

```
select
      child_cnt
      , count(*)
    from
```

Such query will return 1 column of your object type, so this should work.

You may also use your query, but fetch result into 2 number variables.
Or create explicit cursor for this query and record of this cursor_name%rowtype, 
like

```
CURSOR cChildCntCursor IS SELECT ... your query here;
rChildCntCursor cChildCntCursor%ROWTYPE;
```

than you will have ability to fetch.

But much more simple way is to use implicit cursor like:

```
For res in (SELECT child_cnt , count(*) as cnt ... your query here)
Loop
--your processing here
end loop;
```

In such case you don't need to declare res variable.

It will be declared automatically as record with fields child_cnt and cnt (you may use other aliases in your query, then you will have another field names).
You also don't need open, fetch and close this cursor - it is done implicitly.

And it is much more usefull in your case to use static SQL instead of dynamic (write SQL in code but not in string literal).

It will be checked at compile time and will treck dependencies.

Dynamic SQL is powerfull instrument for cases when yhou don't know your query at compile time because it depends on some runtime parameters (as I can see, this is not your case). But it is not checked at compile time and Oracle can't track dependencies for dynamic SQL, so it is much less safe.